# Java - How can I check for the next upcoming space in a string? (For IRC Bot)

Tags: java, string, bots, irc

Obviously, for an IRC bot, input is generated by a user typing a single string, usually with a command and a few arguments, each separated by a space.  I am coding an IRC bot using Java and would like to parse arguments that might vary in character length and save them into multiple strings for use later.  I would like to make a command that looks something like this:

```
bot.command argument1 argument2 argument3
```

and I want it to be so that if the message starts with `bot.command`, then `user` will store `argument1`, `time` will store `argument2`, and `date` will store `argument3`.  The thing is, though, that `argument1`, `argument2`, and `argument3` could vary in character length, so doing something like `time = message.substring(33, message.length())` will stop reading at the end of the argument, but it won't always read the string where the `argument3`'s text begins.  I need to detect where the separator space is and start reading `argument3` from one character after that.  And I can't use If statements to determine what the arguments might be, because they could be anything.  Here's a template, if the above paragraph isn't clear:

```
String message //= the IRC message and bot input
String user;
String time;
String date;
if (message.startsWith("bot.command")) {
    user = message.substring(13, detect next space here and stop reading one character before);
    time = message.substring(detect where previous space was and start one character after that, end before next space);
    date = message.substring(detect where previous space was and start one character after that, message.length());
}
```

I hope that kind of illustrates what I'm trying to do.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: take a look at `indexOf` or maybe even `split`.

Comment: try split, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: maybe an answer to a similar question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** (Removed StringTokenizer example) -

Since `StringTokenizer` is apparently "legacy", I would use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) like this -

```
String message = "BOT.command USER_X    THIS_IS_A_TIME THIS_IS_A_DATE";
String user = null;
String time = null;
String date = null;
// Use toLowerCase - assuming it's case insensitive.
if (message.toLowerCase()
    .startsWith("bot.command")) {
  Scanner st = new Scanner(message);
  if (st.hasNext()) {
    st.next();
  }
  if (st.hasNext()) {
    user = st.next();
  }
  if (st.hasNext()) {
    time = st.next();
  }
  if (st.hasNext()) {
    date = st.next();
  }
}
System.out.printf(
    "User = %s,  Time = %s, Date = %s\n", user,
    time, date);
```

Output is

```
User = USER_X,  Time = THIS_IS_A_TIME, Date = THIS_IS_A_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you!  This seemed to be the best and clearest option to me.  Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using String.split, which breaks up a string into an array using a delimiter regular expression. In your case, you might do:

```
String[] args = message.split("\\s+");
if (args[0].equals("bot.command"))
{
    user = args[1];
    ...
}
```

The reason I'm splitting on the pattern `\s+` (matches one or more whitespace characters) instead of just a space is that this way the program won't crash if the arguments are separate by more than one space or by something like a tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking user input where you are not sure about how many space separated input words will be entered, you can do the following:

```
String[] terms = message.split("\\s+");
for(String word1 : terms) {
//    doSomething() 
}
```

But in your case, you just need 3 arguments, hence the looping will be done 3 times in the for loop.